# Can I use Pokemon Go while I set mobile data off?

Tags: pokemon-go, ios

I travel for China now and don't have any local SIM. I have my Japanese carrier's SIM put in my iPhone but set data roaming off. I use Wi-Fi in hotel.

However, I can use GPS while traveling around in my iPhone. In this case, can I play Pokemon Go while traveling? Or is mobile data required to play the game?

*While I travel for China right now, I want to make the post more general. So please consider another country such as Australia, if China doesn't fit the question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a connection to the internet in order to play Pokemon Go.

This need not necessarily be mobile data, you can play on wi-fi, but since wi-fi is limited range, it's unlikely you will be able to play very well.

Many places have public wi-fi, I'm sure that some of these places would have a Pokestop nearby. In this case you could collect from the Pokestop as well as place lures on it in order to catch Pokemon.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely won't play it in Wi-Fi; if GPS only cannot be played, I will get my SIM.

Comment: Would this even work?  China's firewall blocks a lot of stuff.  You should try it on wifi and see if it even connects.  Local SIM won't work if local wifi won't work.

Comment: @Nelson As I said please consider the question country-agnostic. As to China, it would not be playable anyway as the app has not been released there. But my Apple Account region is Japan, where the app has not been released either, and hence I couldn't even try on it...

Comment: I guess the problem with making it country agnostic is it really can't.  The game works off GPS data so they WILL know where you are.  There's no way around it.